# How to solve this differential equation using RK4 in C++?

Tags: ode, c++, numerical-modelling

I have been given the following homework question to solve:

[image: image of equations]

I am having trouble writing a RK4 solver in C++ for this ODE. I am also not sure how to plot my solution. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream> //Header file for cin & cout
#include <cmath>    //Header file for mathematical operartions
#include <iomanip>  //Header file for precession
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; //calling the standard directory
float F(float y, float x)
{ return 0; }


int main()
{
  float y0,x0,z0,y1, z1,n,h,f,k1,k2,k3,k4, j1, j2, j3, j4;
  cout<<"\nEnter the value of x0 (initial value): "; //Entering the initial values of x & y
  cin>>x0;
  cout<<"\nEnter the value of y0 (initial value): ";
  cin>>y0;
  cout<<"\nEnter the value of z : ";
  cin>>z0;
  cout<<"\nEnter the value of h (step size): ";//Entering the width of step size
  cin>>h;
  cout<<"\nEnter the value of last point of x: ";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"\nStart point (x,y) : "<<x0<<", "<<y0<<endl;

  for( ; x0<n; x0=x0+h){
    f=F(x0,y0);
    k1 = h * f;
    f = F(x0+h/2,y0+k1/2);
    k2 = h * f;
    f = F(x0+h/2,y0+k2/2);
    k3 = h * f;
    f = F(x0+h/2,y0+k2/2);
    k4 = h * f;

    k1=z0;
    j1=-x0*y0;
    k2=z0+(0.5)*j1;
    j2=-(x0+(0.5)*h)*(y0+(0.5)*k1);
    k3=z0+(0.5)*j2;
    j3=-(x0+(0.5)*h)*(y0+(0.5)*k2);
    k4=z0+j3;
    j4=-(x0+h)*(y0+k3);

    y1=y0+(h/6)*(k1+2*(k2)+2*(k3)+k4);
    z1=z0+(h/6)*(j1+2*(j2)+2*(j3)+j4);

    cout<<"\n k1 = "<<k1;
    cout<<"\n k2 = "<<k2;
    cout<<"\n k3 = "<<k3;
    cout<<"\n k4 = "<<k4;
    cout<<"\n j1 = "<<j1;
    cout<<"\n j2 = "<<j2;
    cout<<"\n j3 = "<<j3;
    cout<<"\n j4 = "<<j4<<endl;
    cout<<"\n x = "<<x0+h<<" and y = "<<y1<<endl;
    y0=y1; //take new point for next calculation
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether this homework question must be implemented in C++. I realize that you tagged C++ but was this your choice or your instructors? We already have one answer assuming another language can be used and I think it would be useful to clear this up. Other languages like matlab or python would probably be easier at least for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are asked to plot current with respect to time. I will recommend you to use MATLAB because it has an inbuilt solver for the 4th order RK method and therefore you won't need to write your own code. Plotting in MATLAB is pretty easy and clean as well.

In one of my assignments, I solved an equation called Falkner Skan Flow Equation in MATLAB though [I wrote my own code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50460-falkner-skan-solution--without-using-ode45--fundamental-program) as you have done in C++.

On the same website, called MATLAB File Exchange, you can find other codes which can help you a lot in understanding RK method and its application to differential equations. If you are insisted to use C++, you can see algorithm in my code and implement the same in your program. Also, you can check your C++ results with MATLAB RK solver's results

Comment: after reading the question, you get the impression that the op can simply use a built-in matlab solver? I think the exercise *requires* them to write their own rk4 method.

Comment: What function is Matlab's inbuilt RK4 solver exactly?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : There is none. The file exchange has ode1 to ode4, where the last is RK4.